# simplest way to rename multiple files in a folder?

Tags: python

I have files with names like below and i need to change that to the right side format.

```
CK-123443-1.dft  - CK-123443.dft
CK-123344-A.dft  - CK-123344.dft
123322-B.dft     - 123322.dft
```

I tried using split('-') but this is not working for all files because some files have two hipen and some have one. can I get any other solution for this problem?

My Code with re:
i am not sure about the re-expression

```
import re
new = re.sub('-', '.', old)
```

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: why dont you try, mv command along with *.dft  wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that every filename in the directory has a hyphen that needs to be removed, you can split at hyphens and only exclude the last split part.

So, something like this:

```py
name, ext = file_name.split('.')  # Get the 'dft' part aside

new_name = ''.join(name.split('-')[:-1]) + f'.{ext}'
```

Comment: you can use `rsplit()`

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
import re
#assuming that your file is called file_name
new_name = re.sub('-[A-Za-z0-9]\.', '.', file_name)
#this replaces the characters after the last hyphen and before the extension.
```

I think you can easily do it using regex - before I tell you what pattern to match though, I need some more clarity on how you want the name to change - do you want to maintain any leading alphabet characters and remove all trailing characters after a hyphen and before the extension?

Comment: I don't need anything after the last hipen and i need to keep the same file extension

Comment: I need all the leading characters before last hipen and file extension